# registerForActivityResult callback is not getting called

Tags: android, android-13, registerforactivityresult

I am trying to select media from public storage using `ActivityResultAPI` but it never ever triggers the callback function.

It was working perfectly fine until I move the `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` to **33**.

Here is the `ActivityResultLauncher`

```
private var fileChooserLauncher =
    registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "registerForActivityResult: ${it}")
    }
```

And here is how I am launching this:

```
    val contentSelectionIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
    contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
    contentSelectionIntent.type = "image/*"

    val chooserIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER)
    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent)


    fileChooserLauncher.launch(chooserIntent)
```

Things I already tried but didn't work

1. Getting `READ_MEDIA_IMAGES` permission
2. Adding/removing `android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"` from Activity in `AndroidManifest.xml`
3. Adding/removing `android:exported="true"` from Activity in `AndroidManifest.xml`
4. Testing on Real Devices
5. Testing different contracts such as `GetContent()`

My `build.gradle` app level contains the following libraries and more

```
implementation("androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.6.1")
implementation("androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.5.5")
```

Please help me out on this if you encountered something similar.

Thank you

Comment: Try removing `ACTION_CHOOSER`. And I recommend that you update your [mcve] with the `<activity>` element in the manifest for the activity that has this code.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks for the comment. Well, it turned out that I was overriding the `onActivityResult` method and `super.onActivityResult` was not being called. That somehow was restricting the callback of `registerForActivityResult`